# What synchronization primitive should I use to implement a event driver framework in Java?

Tags: java, synchronization, locking, event-driven

I have a looper thread to execute tasks. Other threads can submit tasks to this looper thread. Some tasks are immediate tasks, others are future tasks, which are to be executed after T seconds after submission. I use `PriorityBlockingQueue` to store tasks, where time is used as the priority, so that the first task of the queue is the most imminent task to be executed.

The looper's main loop is as fellows:

```
PriorityBlockingQueue<Event> taskQueue = ...
while (true) {
    if (taskQueue.isEmpty())
        <something>.wait(); // wait indefinitely
    else
        <something>.wait(taskQueue.peek().time - NOW()); // wait for the first task
    Task task = taskQueue.poll(0); // take the first task without waiting
    if (task != null && task.time <= NOW())
        task.execute();
    else if (task != null)
        taskQueue.offer(task); // not yet runnable, put it back
}
```

The looper provides allows other threads (or itself) to submit tasks:

```
public void submitTask (Task task) { // time information is contained in the task.
    taskQueue.offer(task);
    <something>.signal(); // informs the loop thread that new task is avaliable.
}
```

Here, I have only one thread calling `wait()` and multiple threads calling `signal()`. My question is that what synchronization primitive should I use in the place of `<something>`.  There are so many primitives in the `java.util.concurrent` and `java.util.concurrent.lock` package. And there are also the `synchronized` keyword and `Object.wait()/notify()`. Which one fits best here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

j.u.c. package contains DelayedQueue which can satisfy you problem.
Every queued object should implement Delayed interface with getDelay(..) method.

Comment: Seems exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do any of this.

The whole point of the BlockingQueue is that it already manages thread synchronization for you. You do not need to inform other threads that something new is available now.

Just use

```
 taskQueue.take(); // blocks until something is there
```

or

```
 taskQueue.poll(1, SECONDS); // wait for a while then give up
```

For your "future tasks" that should not be processed immediately, I would not add them to this queue at all. You can use a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to add them to the task queue once it is time (in effect, a second queue).

Come to think of it, you can do away with the BlockingQueue altogether and just use the ScheduledExecutorService (backed by a single thread, your "looper") for all your tasks.

Comment: If the queue is not empty, `poll(1, SECONDS)` will always return immediately.

Comment: Yes, but see my update. You are basically re-implementing ScheduledExecutorService here. Just use the existing one.

Comment: I see. Both `ScheduledExecutorService` and `DelayedQueue` are much better solutions than what I expected. Thanks.